# Counting the number of issued syscalls

Tags: linux, command-line, utilities, system-calls

Is there any tool to count the number of system-calls issued for example in one-second in the entire system (like a global `strace`) ? ( Something like what [vmstat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/vmstat) does for number of interrupts or context switches per second )

Comment: `vmstat` does count the number of syscalls..

Comment: @schily My vmstat(8) output columns are as follows : " r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st" . It doesn't contain  a "sy" column between "in" and "cs" unlike [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/performance/vmstat_command.html)

Comment: The original vmstat on Solaris and BSD has it and even the clone I see on Linux has it.

Comment: @schily do you know where you Linux `vmstat` comes from? The `procps-ng` version [doesn’t track syscalls](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/vmstat.8#L217).

Comment: You might be able to use `sysdig`, but you'd want to filter out the syscalls `sysdig` itself made in the process.

Comment: vmstat --version
vmstat von procps-ng 3.3.10 which version did you check?

Comment: @schily I use vmstat 3.3.12 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @schily 3.3.15, and master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to count system calls with `perf`. If you only want a global count, updated every second, run

```
perf stat -e raw_syscalls:sys_enter -a -I 1000 sleep 5
```

This will show the global count of system calls, every second, for five seconds. The `sleep 5` command determines how long the trace will last; the `-I` parameter determines how often the count will be output.

`perf` can also count calls by type:

```
perf stat -e 'syscalls:sys_enter_*' -a -I 1000 sleep 5
```

or display a `top`-like view of all processes, by system call count, updated every two seconds:

```
perf top -e raw_syscalls:sys_enter -ns comm
```